# .Net MVC - Pass data from child view to layout view (Dynamic Meta Tag Updates)

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-graph-api, model-view-controller, meta-tags

I know that there are duplicate questions on this, but I haven't found the answer yet. So please help. :)

I am trying to change dynamically the meta tag content which is found in my layout view using back-end codes. This is so Facebook can crawl the data when the page is being shared. And until now I am unsuccessful.

It's hard because MVC does not let Viewbag be read in the Layout view. Also, my Layout view is not in the shared folder. And I can't just simply transfer it there.

**UPDATE:** The meta tags are already hard-coded in the Layout View. I just need to update the value of the `content=""` in the meta tags dynamically.

Here are the approaches I have tried:

**Viewbag:** Returns null

Child View

```
ViewBag.Meta1 = model.JobTitleHeading;
ViewBag.Meta2 = model.JobTitleDescription;
```

Layout View

```
var metaTag1 = ViewBag.Meta1;
var metaTag2 = ViewBag.Meta2;
```

**Javascript:** Updates the Meta Tag but Facebook can't crawl the updated data because JS kicks in after page load.

```
$("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", jl1);
$("meta[property='og\\:description']").attr("content", jl2);
```

**HtmlMeta:** Returns null

```
HtmlMeta metaTitle = new HtmlMeta();
HtmlMeta metaDescription = new HtmlMeta();

var placeHolderCheck = metaTitle.FindControl("LayoutPlaceHolder");

if (placeHolderCheck != null)
{

    metaTitle.Attributes.Add("property", "og:title");
    metaTitle.Content = model.Data1;

    Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaTitle);

    metaDescription.Attributes.Add("property", "og:description");
    metaDescription.Content = model.Data2;

    Page.Header.Controls.Add(metaDescription);
}
```

**HttpContext Session:** Updates Meta Tag but session expires. And on first page load the session is null, then on the second page load, the session contains the value from the first session, thus a logical error.

Child view:

```
this.ViewContext.HttpContext.Session["MetaTitle"] = model.Data1;
```

Layout view:

```
string metaHeading = string.Empty;    

metaHeading = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["MetaTitle"];
```

I also tried HttpContext.Current.Items, TempData, PageData, but still get null results.

**I just really want to pass the data from the Controller to the View and then to the Layout view. Or if possible, pass the data from Controller to the Layout view.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into defining sections?
Define a section in your page, set the data in there and make sure the section is specified in the Layout page where it should be, I haven't tried this personally, but from what you are saying, it should make sense.

```
@RenderSection("MetaRender",false)
```

and then in view, use

```
@section MetaRender{...}
```

Have you tried that yet?

Comment: Hi. The thing is, the meta tags are already hard-coded in the Layout View. I just need to update dynamically the `content=""` in the meta tags, that's why I need to pass the data from the controller to the Layout View.

Comment: And if I use Section, that would turn out be a duplicate.

Comment: Is it necessary that they be hard coded?
Wouldn't creating an Html helper help if you can pass in arguments to it?, if none are passed just return default meta? Then you can use session or some other value to automatically set the tags?

Comment: The application is already existing, I couldn't just update the hard codes, a lot of modules are dependent to it. I don't think Html Helper helps. I already tried sessions, as stated above. :)

Comment: How do they specifically depend on the hard codes? Is it after the page has loaded or before?

Comment: The modules have their own views (Child Views). And each view is using the Layout View (Parent view). So whatever code used in Layout will be used by the child views.

Answer (score 0):

Use in Layout View :

```
  <meta name="mymeta1" content="@ViewBag.Meta1" />
  <meta name="mymeta2" content="@ViewBag.Meta2" />
```

It's working either you update values in VIEW or in ACTION.

```
ViewBag.Meta1 = "xyz";
ViewBag.Meta2 = "abc";
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. But this is not the answer I'm looking. : ) I'm using data which is in a model from the Controller. MVC doesn't allow direct passing of data from the Controller to Parent View, using ViewBag. Your code will surely work on Controller to Child View, but not on the previous.

Comment: I re-tried as mentioned. Still working.my steps:
1. Create a Model Mydata  with Props Title  and Description.
2. In Home Controller , Set data
      public ActionResult About()
        {  var mdata = new Mydata(); mdata.Title = "My title"; mdata.Description = "My Description";  return View(mdata); }
3. In About.cshtml , I add @model WebApplication3.Models.Mydata
     and @{ ViewBag.Meta1 = Model.Title; ViewBag.Meta2 = Model.Description; }
4. In Layout :
    <meta ..content="@ViewBag.Meta1" />
    <meta ..content="@ViewBag.Meta2" />

I Login in Application & Click About Link & check the source.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, I'll try your detailed answer. :) I'll add a comment soon if I have results.